# List building in Scala

Tags: scala, list

Can anyone explain in detail what this function is doing and what is the use of `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]`?

```
def f(num: Int, arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val l = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]
  arr.foreach(i => {
    println(i)
    (1 to num).foreach(_ => l += i)
  })

  l.toList
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why is it tagged with [tag:replication]? What does this have to do with fault-tolerance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBuffer.empty[Int]` is used for instantiating the `ListBuffer`

`ListBuffer.empty[Int]` is same as `ListBuffer[Int]()`

`ListBuffer` is mutable list.

1. For every value `i` of arr list.
2. i is printed
3. `num` times `i` is added to list buffer

Later the mutable list is converted to immutable list using `toList` call

That means

> every value of `arr` list is added to list buffer `num` times

```
# Scala REPL

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def f(num: Int, arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val l = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]
  arr.foreach(i => {
    println(i)
    (1 to num).foreach(_ => l += i)
  })

  l.toList
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

f: (num: Int, arr: List[Int])List[Int]

scala> f(10, (1 to 10).toList)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks Pamu, it makes sense to me now,

Comment: could share some idea on how to build a list by taking element from user?

Comment: @RupeshKumar `List(elementFromUser)` or u can use `elementFromUser :: Nil`